# How to ensure malicious users won't change cookie value?

Tags: php, security, cookies, userid

I'm developing a login page for a very small site, and for the "remember me button",
I use the user-id which then I encrypt before placing it in the cookie, and when i want to check if he already has a cookie, i uncrypt the value and connect with the user-id given.

But I'm sure that's not secured enough and people will just have to set a cookie with a random value with encrypting and this will make the job, isn't it ?

As solution to this could be to generate a random token, put it in cookie and in database. Then, if you have the token, you can connect.
If user get stolen this token, this is not the page problem isn't it ?

But I don't know how to process differently..
Anyone has a solution ?

Comment: What process are you using to encrypt the ID? Assuming there's some secret key involved, nobody else would have access to that, so they wouldn't be able to create something that decrypts to a meaningful value on your end.

Comment: I found a function to encrypt with  : `function Encrypt( $value ) {

   $key = hex2bin(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4));

   $cipher = "aes-256-cbc";
   $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
   $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

   $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($value, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv);

   return( base64_encode($ciphertext . '::' . $iv. '::' .$key) );
}`

Comment: You never should trust anything you receive from a client. Which is why I would consider an encrypted authorization cookie a design issue, if that is all the protection you have. The standard approach indeed is a combination of a user and a token which is matched against the last session in the server side database. What speaks again such scheme?

Answer (score 1):

To simply answer the asked question: You can't.
Cookies are stored on the users computer and with enough access rights and/or knowledge the user will be able to delete or modify any cookies your website set.

Encryption is taking information and make into non-sense so no one can access the information. If you need encryption is up to you. But I think this kind of session management is implemented already in a lot of ways. One of the simpler would be some kind of "dynamic API Token"-implementation - Storing some kind of Hash-like String in the cookie and in DB. If they match -> login, if not -> logout. (Symfony example: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authenticator.html )

Another one would be JWT (JSON Web Tokens), these are indeed encrypted because they send information back and forth.

If you want to implement something like this yourself I would suggest to look at documentation about these two to start.